# File readable by only PHP?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, chmod

I'd like to make a file on my server be readable by PHP, but not directly accessible with a browser. Say my Apache installation's root is /apache. I'd like PHP to be able to get the text of `/apache/1.txt`, but not allow the user to go to `domain.tld/1.txt` and view the contents. I'd still like to be able to read/write the file through FTP/SFTP without root.

What would be the propper `chmod` string for this? 642 seems likely, but I'm not sure how PHP accesses the file.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? (Also, making the file world _writable_ is not going to help, so don't do that.)

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm trying to have a bunch of files with data to load into a page, and I'm too lazy to make a database, since it will bever really be edited.

Comment: The *real* correct answer is to not put files you don't want the webserver to serve to people below `DocumentRoot`.  Make a directory somewhere else and have the files loaded from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect all request coming to `/1.txt` to something else using `.htaccess` or `apache` configuration. So, if some one will try to access `domain.tld/1.txt`, it will redirect.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
suku@ubuntu-vm:/var/www/html$ grep info.php /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
        RedirectMatch ^/info.php /html/index.html

suku@ubuntu-vm:/var/www/html$ sudo cat ../info.php 
<?php
phpinfo();
?>

suku@ubuntu-vm:/var/www/html$ cat index.html 
You redirected to here becuase you tried to access localhost/info.php
suku@ubuntu-vm:/var/www/html$ pwd
/var/www/html

suku@ubuntu-vm:/var/www/html$ links http://localhost/info.php -dump
You redirected to here becuase you tried to access localhost/info.php

suku@ubuntu-vm:/var/www/html$ cd ..
suku@ubuntu-vm:/var/www$ ls -l info.php 
-rw-r----- 1 www-data www-data 20 Jan 12 11:25 info.php
```

Comment: And then just `755`?

Comment: `640` is more than enough

Comment: @tkbx See my edit